# jQuery won't change css or animate... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Here is the jsFiddle for what I have at the moment: https://jsfiddle.net/vst5fky5/

I am redoing a Flash section in jQuery. There is a logo and 7 inline list items (navigation) that I need to animate from the top. I want to use jQuery to add top:-5em at the beginning, then have them come down one by one.

Nothing is working. Note: the logo click function is only to test, I would like to have it change CSS, then run through the animations on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav a li').css("top:","-5em");
    $('#logo').click(function(){
        $(".nav a li").animate({top:$(this).offset().top}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't 'update' your question to hide the broken code; that makes the question pointless. And of absolutely no help to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax issue. You have added extra `:` in the following syntax.

```
 $('.nav a li').css("top:","-5em");
```

should be

```
 $('.nav a li').css("top","-5em");
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/qLcrj6wo/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** method to get one by one animation effect

```
$('.nav a li').css("top","-5em");
    $('#logo').click(function(){
        $(".nav a li").each(function(i,e){
          $(e).delay(i*1000).animate({top:$(e).offset().top}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qLcrj6wo/3/)**

Comment: Ok this works better than the way I was going to do it. Thanks for this.